# Fastest way to remove unsafe chars from string but keep unicode characters?

Tags: python, string, security, unicode

I recently ran a test on HackerNews inviting people to come break my web app ([www.tagxt.com](http://www.tagxt.com)).

Some people succeeded in breaking a couple things I'm trying to fix.

The one I'm after here is:

How do I stop people from creating usernames like `../../` and `../logout` but still let them use unicode characters like `☃☃☃☃☃☃` ? Also, the `_` underscore is ok.

Max username length is 15 chars so performance is not a big factor but I would like to find the fastest way to remove dangerous characters.

Comment: Is there a particular reason you need to allow such characters? Generally it's best to restrict the characters that can be used in anything you'd be putting in a URL. (The other option is to, say, not put usernames in URLs.)

Comment: It's less a question of whether URLs can handle unicode, and more a question of why you can't just use a smaller set of characters (or not put full usernames in URLs) that would avoid problems entirely. However, allowing unicode in usernames/URLs can lead to other issues, such as impersonation - there are many unicode characters that look similar or identical to other unicode characters.

Comment: nah, usernames must go in url

Comment: Then I'd highly recommend not allowing unicode in usernames.

Comment: may i ask: what is it exactly that makes you feel that way?

Comment: Tell me - could you tell http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0410/index.htm apart from a regular A? http://pastebin.com/Fj3hZN5m

Comment: i don't terribly care if they can be typed in. as long as a clickable link will work, i'm ok

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17631/discussion-between-amber-and-chrickso)

Comment: First work out _exactly_ what you need to do, and _then_ look for a faster way _if_ you need it to be faster. BTW, putting unicode in the url is a dumb idea.

Comment: may i ask: what is it exactly that makes you feel that way?

Comment: Why is having a username like `../../` or `../logout` a problem? You're not creating files with user-supplied filenames are you? There is no such thing as an unsafe character, only an unsafe way of using it - typically: failing to escape it correctly for the context you're putting it in. For URL path parts, use URL-encoding (%xx). Unicode characters can be included in path paths if UTF-8-URL-encoded (as per IRI).

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this:

```
list = ["A", "B", "C"...]
for i in list:    
    string1 = "../../"
    if i in string1:
        print("Error")
```

I'm not so sure...

Answer (score 0):

The fastest way to validate characters is to create a white list of all allowed characters:

```
allowed = [ 'A','B','C'...]
```

If this seems tedious, use a library such as OWASP ESAPI